What is the alternative way for android development without android studio?
I want to be an Android developer. As Android Studio is hungry for memory, I don't have enough memory for Android Studio on my computer. But I want to continue android development without Android Studio.
I tried to build a project without Android Studio. Firstly, I set up Android SDK on my system. Then I built a maven project using Visual Studio code. I added the dependency androidx. But I couldn't have appcompat in androidx. That's why I couldn't continue.
Again, Android Studio has Layout Editor in which Android UI components can be dragged and dropped. As I don't want to use Android Studio, I couldn't find any tools that I can drag and drop the UI components and it will translate the design to XML.
So I want a proper guideline if there is an alternative way to continue android development. If so, please help me from the beginning. How to build project and add all libraries I need? And how to design android layout easily?

You want everything but at no costs, sorry but that won't work. You can develop Android apps with just a text editor and directly run gradle tasks, however there will be no help from an IDE with code completion and hints on how to solve errors. If your PC is too old to run Android Studio this is the way to go. As you have noticed this isn't an easy way as you have to know that you can not mix androidx with old support libraries.

If you don't want to use Android Studio, here are a few alternatives:
Set up Visual Studio Code (VSCode) for Android Development:

You can use VSCode for Android development by installing extensions
like "Kotlin" or "Java" for language support, and "Gradle for Java"
to build your project.

You'll need to set up the Android SDK manually and configure Gradle
scripts. While this gives you the flexibility to code in a
lightweight environment, it won't have advanced features like
drag-and-drop UI design or complete code assistance.


Use Project IDX:

Project IDX is a new browser-based IDE from Google that supports
Android development. It provides a lightweight, cloud-based
alternative to Android Studio and allows you to develop Android apps
without installing a heavy IDE on your computer.
You can register for Project IDX if you already have access or
request access through the registration link. IDX offers features
similar to Android Studio but runs in the cloud, making it ideal if
your local machine lacks the required computational power.

Consider Android Studio via Project IDX (Cloud IDE):

If you want Android Studio-like features but don't have enough
computational power, you can also use the cloud version of Android
Studio through Project IDX. It provides you with a full-featured
Android development environment accessible from your browser.(Registration link)


When it comes to android development, I'll prefer to use Android Studio always. because it has more compatibility and debugging is way more better than any other IDE specially for Android development.

"How can you ride bike without a bike?"

